# Sending waypoints to navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know how to send mutliple goals to a robot that doesn't have LaseScan to create a map.

- Using the [diff_drive package](https://github.com/merose/diff_drive) , I managed to visualize the movement of the real robot on rviz (`diff_drive_odometry`) and to make it achieve one goal after another (`diff_drive_go_to_goal`). the connection (rosserial_python) isn't perfect but the robot can achieve the goal.
- Now, I am want to make my robot follow a path. I saw we could use waypoints but I am not really sure about how to do this. Currently, I am subscribing to `move_base_simple/goal` to send a goal and when the robot achieves its goal, the client can send another goal but in most of the examples I saw, `move_base` is used, what are the differences between these two ?

Thanks in advance,

Shanika

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329062/sending-waypoints-to-navigation-stack/) by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS  [navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) stack is based on move_base and uses global and local planners and costmaps .  I dont know much about the diff_drive package you linked but what I can see from description is that it is a "lighter-weight" solution than the ROS controller framework and uses  [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) and PID to calculate velocities. Also I see that is subscribes to `move_base_simple/goal` just to grab the goal given via the RViz 2D Nav goal plugin.  
As for the waypoint navigation, you can write your own node that can send multiple waypoints using  [SimpleActionClient](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient) from  actionlib. Also there are some packages like the [follow_waypoints](http://wiki.ros.org/follow_waypoints) that already have some implementation of waypoint navigation.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-07-23**:
In order to use `move_base`, does the robot need to have LaserScan ? In my case, the robot only has an ultrasound sensor.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-07-23**:
This can ask this as a separate question. You should check for existing layers like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer) one and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/205808/robot-navigation-using-ultrasound-and-ir-sensors/) question might have some info.

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-07-24**:
I will check these links before asking in a separate question. Thank you for your answer ^^